# Handling duplicate elements in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am building an app which features a kind of "playlist". This is represented an ng-repeated custom directive with `ng-repeat = "element in playlist"`

Because I want to allow a user to re-use the same element twice in the playlist, I tried using the `track by $index` addition.

Now, what's confusing is: when I came to remove an element from the playlist (I have a function `removeElement(index)` which essentially contains something like this:

```
$scope.removeElement = function(index){
  $scope.playlist.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Something weird happened: the element was removed correctly from `$scope.playlist`, but for some reason the view didn't update properly. The last element appeared to be removed.

Furthermore, I couldn't properly re-order the elements in the array either.

When I removed `track by $index` this problem disappears, so I assume this is because when you remove an item from the array, if you're only looking at the indices, then it appears you've just deleted the last one.

The behaviour is odd though, because transcluded content is correctly removed -- **[see this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4znEquMeQvIUZAmPjWdL?p=preview)**

**EDIT:** The above link has been modified to show the problem better and also show the answer I settled on.

The question has also been slightly edited, to make it clearer what I was getting at. KayakDave's answer below is still correct, but is more suited to an array of primitives (which my original plunker featured).

**TL;DR:** How do you put duplicate elements in an `ng-repeat` without sacrificing the ability to control their position, or remove elements correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd like to add another answer to this question, because I discovered a simpler solution.

There's an important [section of the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat%3adupes) for `ng-repeat` which is easy to miss, specifically on the dupes error.

It states:

> By default, collections are keyed by reference

After reading this, the solution was obvious - as I wasn't dealing with primitives (*yes, the plunker is, but that was an over-simplification*) I needed to **copy** the duplicate object and add its copy to the array. This means everything works as expected when you **remove track by $index** and just let the default behaviour take over.

Angular makes this especially easy because jqlite has a `.copy`. method.

Here's what I'm saying **[demonstrated in a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4znEquMeQvIUZAmPjWdL?p=preview)**.

Comment: Could you post an updated plunker showing this? It seems like this would result in the same issue- since it doesn't seem like the issue is the collection/object key but it's correlation to `$index` which I'd expect to still be mismatched.  So I'm curious to see what I'm missing. And it would help others who have the same issue as you posted to better understand your solution.

Comment: You're right - what I neglected to say here is that this is an alternative to using `track by $index`. `track by $index` is needed for primitives, but for the playlist example in my post it makes more sense to copy the track you want to include twice than to track by index (as re-ordering is a very likely requirement).

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks for the update.  If you have a moment you might tweak your question some too- right now you summarize your question as "How do you correctly remove an element from an ng-repeat array if you are using track by $index?" and I think you're answering a broader question now.  Just so this all helps future generations  :)

Comment: absolutely - I will edit that now. I've demonstrated better with a plunker.

Answer (score 7):

One of the big performance advantages of using `track by` is Angular doesn't touch any DOM element whose tracking expression hasn't changed.  This is a huge performance improvement for long `ng-repeat` lists and one of the reasons for the addition of `track by`.

That performance optimization is at the root of what you're seeing.

When you use `$index` in `track by` you're telling `ng-repeat` to tie each DOM element it creates to it's position (`$index`) on the first run of `ng-repeat`.

So the element with color style red is tagged 0, orange 1, yellow 2 ... and finally indigo 5.

When you delete a color Angular looks at the indexes you told it to track and sees that you longer have an index #5 (since your list is one shorter than before).  Therefore it removes the DOM element tagged 5- which has a color style of "indigo".  You still have an index #2 so the element with the color yellow stays.

What makes it confusing is that, due to data binding, the text inside the DOM element does get updated.  Thus when you delete "yellow" the DOM element with the color yellow gets the text "green".

In short what you're seeing is **`ng-repeat` leaving the DOM element styled with yellow untouched because it's tracking value (2) still exists but data binding has updated the text inside that element.**

In order to add multiple entries with the same color **you need to add your a unique identifier to each entry** that you use for the `track by`.  One approach is to use key-value pairs for each entry where the key is your unique identifier.  Like so:

```
$scope.colorlist = {1:'red', 2:'orange',3:'yellow',4:'green',5:'blue',6:'indigo',7:'yellow'};
```

Then `track by` the key as follows:

```
<color-block ng-repeat="(key, color) in colorlist track by key" color="{{color}}" ng-transclude>
    {{color}}
</color-block>
```

And make sure to use that key for your delete select:

```
<option value="{{key}}" ng-repeat="(key,color) in colorlist">{{color}}</option>
```

Now the DOM element with the color styling yellow is tied to the key you specified for the "yellow" array element.  So when you delete "yellow" the `ng-repeat` will remove the correct DOM element and everything works.

You can see it work here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/cFaU8WIjliRjPI6LInZ0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, this is a really thorough explaination. Track by colour works for my plunker, but the reason for putting in `track by $index` was so that I could have duplicate elements in the list. `track by color` would mean I couldnt have `["red", "blue", "red"]` -- are there alternatives? **EDIT** I realise I should have included a duplicate in my plunkr list to make my question clearer by the way ;)

Comment: You can.  I updated the answer to cover handling multiple elements (using a unique identifier).